# Safe way for communicating safely between two linux machines and executing a script on receiver?

Tags: linux, networking

I have a CI service which allows me to run Linux commands on events, such as 'build success', on the host Linux machine (A).
I have my app running on another Linux machine (B). 
I would like to send a message, A --> B, when the success event triggers, and run a script on B to update my application.

- I have the IP of machine B and I also have the 'on success' event set
  up on A.
- I have my update script already written on machine B as well.

All I need is a safe way of networking this message and a way for the receiver to trigger a script, I assume?

I would love the help! Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried to research this on your own? What did you find? Why don't those solutions work for you? Where are you stuck implementing them?

Answer (score 1):

Ansible is a popular IT automation framework that can distribute tasks over networked resources using SSH, WinRM, or other connection plugins.